# What is is the simplest way to setup a local rdf triple store with SPARQL endpoint?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, triplestore, triples

For learning SPARQL it might be useful to have full control both over the query text and the data (RDF triples). While there are many public SPARQL endpoints available their data is typically read-only for obvious reasons. To actively apply SPARQL-queries to ones own data, a local triple store might be useful, e.g. for reproducing the examples from https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/.

However, setting up such an infrastructure with all its dependencies might be complicated.

→ What is the *simplest*¹ way to setup a local triple store with SPARQL endpoint on a usual PC?

(¹: The meaning of "simplest" depends on ones system configuration and prior knowledge, which can be reflected by different answers.)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/ is SPARQL 1.0 and superseded by https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/ which is SPARQl 1.1.

Answer (score 3):

A java based solution is:

https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi

Down the Apache Jena Fuseki zip.
Unpack the zip, run `fuseki-server`.
Goto `http://localhost:3030/`

Answer (score 2):

If one has already a Python environment then [rdflib-endpoint](https://github.com/vemonet/rdflib-endpoint) provides a simple solution with only two commands

- `pip install rdflib-endpoint` (run once)
- `rdflib-endpoint serve <path_to_your_triple-file(s)>`
- Access the YASGUI SPARQL editor on http://localhost:8000

Comment: Technically a SPARQL endpoint, but implementation-wise more or less an rdflib wrapper. So don't expect it to scale for larger datasets w.r.t. performance. But for learning SPARQL ok. Of course Java based solutions like Apache Jena Fuseki or RDF4J also don't need anzthing but Java installed. The rest is just downloading and starting. For Virtuoso or Blazegraph you also just need Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe https://triplydb.com is interesting for you. You can create datasets like this. https://triplydb.com/Triply/linkedmdb/sparql/linkedmdb

Answer (score 1):

Using [Eclipse RDF4J](https://rdf4j.org/) via docker:

```
docker pull eclipse/rdf4j-workbench:latest
docker run -p 8080:8080 eclipse/rdf4j-workbench:latest
```

and then access at http://localhost:8080/rdf4j-workbench

Answer (score 1):

oxigraph ( https://github.com/oxigraph/oxigraph ) !
(also you may find related project interesting https://crates.io/crates/reasonable )

And btw. it looks like rdflib-endpoint (mentioned earlier) can via `rdflib-endpoint --store Oxigraph ...`  be configured to use oxigraph!

```
cargo install oxigraph_server
mkdir -p oxigraph_data
oxigraph_server --location oxigraph_data load -f example.ttl 
oxigraph_server --location oxigraph_data serve
```

And you can check it in browser (probably on http://localhost:7878/ ) or form command line:

```
curl -G 'http://localhost:7878/query' --data-urlencode "query=PREFIX rdf:
 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 SELECT ?sub ?pred ?obj WHERE {
   ?sub ?pred ?obj .
 } LIMIT 10" -H "Accept: application/sparql-results+json"|jq
```

---

copy from https://crates.io/crates/oxigraph_server#usage

### Usage

Run `oxigraph_server --location my_data_storage_directory serve` to start the server where `my_data_storage_directory` is the directory where you want Oxigraph data to be stored. It listens by default on `localhost:7878`.

The server provides an HTML UI, based on [YASGUI](https://yasgui.triply.cc/), with a form to execute SPARQL requests.

---

OR

Via Docker:

Copy from https://crates.io/crates/oxigraph_server#using-a-docker-image :

---

### Using a Docker image

#### Display the help menu

```
docker run --rm ghcr.io/oxigraph/oxigraph --help
```

#### Run the Webserver

Expose the server on port `7878` of the host machine, and save data on the local `./data` folder

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/data:/data -p 7878:7878 ghcr.io/oxigraph/oxigraph --location /data serve --bind 0.0.0.0:7878
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77737438/544721
```

You can then access it from your machine on port `7878`:

```
# Open the GUI in a browser
firefox http://localhost:7878

# Post some data
curl http://localhost:7878/store?default -H 'Content-Type: text/turtle' -T ./data.ttl

# Make a query
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/sparql-results+json' -H 'Content-Type: application/sparql-query' --data 'SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10' http://localhost:7878/query

# Make an UPDATE
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/sparql-update' --data 'DELETE WHERE { <http://example.com/s> ?p ?o }' http://localhost:7878/update
```